# How to get the address of a journal's editorial department and use it in a cover letter

Tags: journals, paper-submission, elsevier

I am writing a cover letter for submitting a manuscript to Computers & Graphics (Elsevier) journal. I saw a [template](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjIoJ-g643fAhUCk3AKHQIOB0gQFjAAegQIChAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.elsevier.com%2F__data%2Fpromis_misc%2FAJPS_Author%2520Template.doc&usg=AOvVaw1bf2s3GN7QMA9aNUqEKjgi) for a cover letter of a different journal (AJPS), which goes as:

> December 26, 2007
>   Editorial Department of Asian Journal Pharmaceutical Sciences
>   Shenyang Pharmaceutical University
>   No.103, Wenhua Road, Shengyang 110016, China

I am not sure where to get the address for CAG journal from. It’s not mentioned anywhere on the [journal website](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/computers-and-graphics/).

Comment: If you are submitting electronically, you do not need to include their physical address. If you still need it, contact the journal (they should have an email address or telephone number listed in their contact information) and ask them.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo You could turn that comment into an answer.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo thanks a lot, it seems physical address is not required

Answer (score 1):

On the bottom of  [Computer & Graphics](https://ees.elsevier.com/cag/default.asp),

Click  "Editorial Office" button.

You get their e-mail address, if that's what you're looking for.

If you want their physical address, click "About Us" button on the bottom, you get Elsevier address.

Comment: Well I was actually looking for physical address (being unsure if there is a need to enter one), though it appears asking them would be a better idea. So thanks a lot!

Comment: @n.gaurav Answer edited to include physical address of Elsevier address.